# How to convert Export Data > CSV from blockchain.com to a http request?

Tags: google-chrome, html, javascript, website

I want to get the link for the Export Data > CSV at the bottom right of the chart so I can script the end-user behavior into a script but every time I right click to get the URL it immediately downloads the file. What is the button doing because it doesn't have the usual menu where you can right click and then "Copy link address" Does any one know what the web browser is doing when the end user clicks on the button? The website is https://www.blockchain.com/charts/n-transactions

At the bottom right of the chart, when I click on Export Data > CSV it just automatically downloads the CSV file. If I try to right click to determine the URL that I can use in an html request, it automatically downloads the CSV file. I should be able to script the same behavior that occurs as an end user but it seems like its not possible. Does anyone know what request is being sent to the web page to to download the CSV file?

I'm using Chrome.

On Edge I was able to figure out the downlink was

blob:https://www.blockchain.com/75c62e22-d452-40bc-920f-38a4219f49b5

What does this mean? and what is the random string afterwards? The link works in Edge but not in Chrome.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] I think that this questions needs both more details and more focus. Please specify one web browser and brief description of your search and research efforts as is suggested in [ask]. As you already are looking at the page DOM it would be nice, I think, if you refer to the node elements by their HTML tag names (in this quest is an option from a selector, not a button)

Comment: Ok I will try - the terms are new to me so I'm not sure how to refer to each item yet but I will try. For the web browser, I was using chrome. I don't know how the website converts the selector into an action.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays is common to find websites that where optimized for performance, security, etc. That looks to be the case of blockchaing.com as there is not a "link" directly attached to the referred "button".

You could use the Chrome DevTools to analyze how the button works but you should learn about modern web development. In this specific case you need to learn about JavaScript *event listeners* and how to "debug" them using Chrome DevTools. Also you might need to learn about *AJAX*.

**Related**

- [How do I view events fired on an element in Chrome DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213703/1595451)

**Resources**

MDN Glossary entries:

- [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/element)
- [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX)